# Scheme keyword is unbound

Tags: scheme, modulo

When I type the following lambda expression in to a scheme terminal `((lambda(x) (modulo x 4)) 4)` why do i get an error stating that the symbol modulo is unbound when it's a keyword ?

Comment: Also, using [Alexandria Morgan's picture](http://instagram.com/p/uyspYSJfcl/) for your avatar is kind of creepy. It's better to use your own picture, or none at all.

Comment: Who knows, it might be her :D

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Wouldn't Scheme be a natural leap from french horn and french bread :-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you're using a restricted sublanguage that offers only limited functionality. What Scheme implementation are you using, and are you in some kind of restricted module that doesn't import the standard Scheme procedures?

`modulo` is indeed a standard part of Scheme and is included in any standard Scheme system. (It is, however, not a "keyword", in either the "reserved word" sense (Scheme has no reserved words), nor the named parameters sense (where keywords look like `#:this`).)